# Convert list of integers into list of binary digits

Tags: python, function, binary

Create a function that takes as input a list of integers, and which outputs a list of the binary digit lists obtained from your `integertobinary()` function. The order in which the binary digit lists appear should match the order of the list of input integers.

For example, if the input to your function is `[14,3,8,5]` the output should be `[[1,1,1,0],[1,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1]]`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def integertobinary(L): 
    for n in L:
        y = []
        while(n>0):
            a=n%2
            y.append(a)
            n=n//2
        y.reverse()
    return y

    print(integertobinary([5,6,7,8,9]))
```

As a result, I am getting: `[1, 0, 0, 1]` when I am supposed to get `[[1,1,1,0],[1,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1]]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seems to be that you clear the value of y in every iteration. You need to make another variable to store all the values. The code might be:

```
def integertobinary(L): 
    y = []
    for n in L:
        z = []
        while(n>0):
            a=n%2
            z.append(a)
            n=n//2
        z.reverse()
        y.append(z)
    return y
print(integertobinary([5,6,7,8,9]))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful! What would I do if I want an output like this: [[1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1]]? so that all of the lists of binary digits for all of the numbers in the list have the same length

Comment: @Effectivelearning You could run a loop to append `4-len(element)` zeroes to the element. But since append works only from right, you can either use modules or append before reversing

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a simpler pythonic way, if you don't have a requirement of writing binary conversion logic. Just use the `format` or `bin` function in python for this.
An eg.

```
def integertobinary(L):
    return [[int(b) for b in format(i, "04b")] for i in L]
```

would do the exact need. `"04b"` gives a binary formatted value with padding upto 4 leading zeroes.

```
print(integertobinary([14, 3, 8, 5]))
```

gives output

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this on a 1-D list could be:

```
a=  [14,3,8,5]
bin_list = [list(map(int, list(f"{x:b}"))) for x in a]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```